# How to sort part of an XML file using XSL

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to sort an XML file using XSL. I'm pretty new to XSL and have written a .Net app to apply the XSL to the XML and save it to a new file. This works fine. A cut-down version of the XML look like this (astute readers will note that it is a Management Studio project file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SqlWorkbenchSqlProject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="PMISQL">
  <Items>
    <LogicalFolder Name="Connections" Type="2" Sorted="true">
      <Items>
        <ConnectionNode Name="cerberus:XPOOLE\barney.russ">
          <Created>2013-06-28T15:50:27.919788+01:00</Created>
          <Type>SQL</Type>
          <Server>cerberus</Server>
          <UserName />
          <Authentication>Windows Authentication</Authentication>
          <InitialDB>master</InitialDB>
          <LoginTimeout>15</LoginTimeout>
          <ExecutionTimeout>0</ExecutionTimeout>
          <ConnectionProtocol>NotSpecified</ConnectionProtocol>
          <ApplicationName>Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query</ApplicationName>
        </ConnectionNode>
      </Items>
    </LogicalFolder>
    <LogicalFolder Name="Queries" Type="0" Sorted="true">
      <Items>
        <FileNode Name="PMI193_Documents.sql">
          <AssociatedConnectionMoniker>8c91a03d-f9b4-46c0-a305-b5dcc79ff907:tyro:True</AssociatedConnectionMoniker>
          <AssociatedConnSrvName>tyro</AssociatedConnSrvName>
          <AssociatedConnUserName />
          <FullPath>PMI193_Documents.sql</FullPath>
        </FileNode>
        <FileNode Name="PMI002_EventTypes.sql">
          <AssociatedConnectionMoniker>8c91a03d-f9b4-46c0-a305-b5dcc79ff907:cerberus:True</AssociatedConnectionMoniker>
          <AssociatedConnSrvName>cerberus</AssociatedConnSrvName>
          <AssociatedConnUserName />
          <FullPath>PMI002_EventTypes.sql</FullPath>
        </FileNode>
        <FileNode Name="PMI079a_DementiaScreeningDetail.sql">
          <AssociatedConnectionMoniker>8c91a03d-f9b4-46c0-a305-b5dcc79ff907:tyro:True</AssociatedConnectionMoniker>
          <AssociatedConnSrvName>tyro</AssociatedConnSrvName>
          <AssociatedConnUserName />
          <FullPath>PMI079a_DementiaScreeningDetail.sql</FullPath>
        </FileNode>
      </Items>
    </LogicalFolder>
    <LogicalFolder Name="Miscellaneous" Type="3" Sorted="true">
      <Items />
    </LogicalFolder>
  </Items>
  <SccProjectName>$/DataWarehouse/Dev/Reports</SccProjectName>
  <SccAuxPath />
  <SccLocalPath>..</SccLocalPath>
  <SccProvider>MSSCCI:Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider</SccProvider>
</SqlWorkbenchSqlProject>
```

You'll note that there are several LogicalFolder sections. I'm simply interested in sorting the one where the attribute Name="Queries" and I wanted it sorted by the sub-element Items/FileNode/FullPath.

I've taken some XSL which is identity XSL and extended it. It reproduces the original file, but does not sort the section I want it to (in fact it appears to sort nothing). The XSL I've created looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/SqlWorkbenchSqlPro/Items/LogicalFolder/Items">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:sort select="FullPath"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know how to specify that I'm only interested in sorting the section /SqlWorkbenchSqlPro/Items/LogicalFolder/Items where Name="Queries", how to specify which level of elements to sort, and how to specify which element to use to sort the items. Really, I'm not very good at XSL at all as I only started looking at it a few hours ago.

Any help much appreciated. I am getting a headache.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you have built upon the identity template is a good start, so you are not far off. The first problem you have is that your template refers to `SqlWorkbenchSqlPro` but in your XML it is `SqlWorkbenchSqlProject`, so is not matching anything.

But don't go and correct it just yet, because if you did that alone your template would get stuck in a loop. The use of `<xsl:apply-templates select=".">` will just select the same matching template. You should be doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="FileNode" />` here, or just `<xsl:apply-templates />`

But to answer your main question, you can add a condition, in square brackets to target the node you want

```
 <xsl:template match="LogicalFolder[@Name='Queries']/Items">
```

Note there is no need to specify the full path to the node here.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LogicalFolder[@Name='Queries']/Items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="FullPath"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of `xsl:copy` in the `Items` template, to copy the existing `Items`  element before selecting and sorting its child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> How to specify that I'm only interested in sorting the section `LogicalFolder/Items` where `Name="Queries"`

That's very easy. Make the template so that it only matches this particular type of node.

```
<xsl:template match="LogicalFolder[@Name = 'Queries']/Items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
            <xsl:sort select="FullPath" data-type="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This copies the `<Items>` element. After that you don't want to apply templates to `.` (the current node, i.e. `<Items>`) anymore, but to `*` (all its child elements, i.e. `<FileNode>`).

> how to specify which level of elements to sort,

That's very easy, too. Ordering applies to the selected nodes. In the above case, all child elements are selected. That means ordering is limited to the top level of elements under `LogicalFolder/Items`.

Assuming there can be nested `<Items>` and you want to sort recursively, all you need to do is change the template to apply to *all* nodes `<Items>` inside a `LogicalFolder[@Name = 'Queries']` by changing the `match` expression like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Items[ancestor::LogicalFolder[@Name = 'Queries']]">
```

No other change necessary, the XSLT processor does the recursion for you. (`<xsl:apply-templates>` is the recursive step).

> and how to specify which element to use to sort the items

The select expression in `<xsl:sort>` always is relative to the node being ordered. In the above,

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*">
```

selects a bunch of `<FileNode>` elements, which means

```
<xsl:sort select="FullPath" data-type="text" />
```

is correct. (`data-type` added because it's good practice, not because it's strictly necessary. `text` is the default.)